# Wordpress redirects to an unknown link

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've installed a clean Wordpress environment. After that, every page redirects to a construction like the following one.

```
http://test.com/test.com/wp-admin/
```

All pages does work well, but this has to be solved.
So I've checked the general sitesettings and changed it's base URL to what it should be.
After that, the homepage of the website still redirects to the old construction but now ends on a 404. All other pages are working fine now with the correct URL.

How can I change or remove this redirect?

Comment: Check the .htaccess file in your root if you haven't yet. Could be something left over.

Comment: Thank you!
I don't see anything unusual in my htaccess.

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Answer (score 0):

in this article says how to set URL
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

for example you can edit
Edit wp-config.php
It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.

Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

or
Edit functions.php
If you have access to the site via FTP, then this method will help you quickly get a site back up and running, if you changed those values incorrectly.

1. FTP to the site, and get a copy of the active theme's functions.php file. You're going to edit it in a simple text editor and upload it back to the site.
2. Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial "

update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );

or

1. Change WordPress URL in Admin Dashboard
   The first and most common method is to change your WordPress URL directly from within the admin dashboard. On the left-hand side, under “Settings,” click into “General.” You can then update the following:

WordPress Address (URL): The address to reach your blog.
Site Address (URL): The address of your WordPress core files.
Both should match unless you are giving WordPress it’s own directory. Remember that after you click “Save Changes,” your WordPress dashboard is now only accessible via the new URL.

change wordpresd address URL

Comment: Thank you!
This is what I've already did and solved my first issue indeed. But now I'm stuck with a redirect to the old situation just on the homepage as said. That's what I wanted to be solved.

Comment: try to clear the history of browser ,  add to  wp-config.phpdefine('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');